# Showing that $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is a topological space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

**Definition:**

Let $X$ be a set.

A set $\tau \subset P(X)$ is called a topology on $X$ if:

(a) $\emptyset , X\in \tau$

(b) $A,B\in \tau$ implies $A\cap B\in \tau$

(c) If $\alpha \in \tau$ then $\underset{A\in \alpha}\bigcup A\in \tau$.

I have been given $$\tau :=\left \{ U\subset \mathbb{R} : \text{ For every } x\in U \text{ exists } \varepsilon >0 \text{ with } (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)\subset U\right \}$$
Show that$(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is a topological space

**My attempt:**

In order to show that $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\in \tau$ , I'd say that if $\varepsilon \to 0$, we have $(x,x)=\emptyset$ and if $\varepsilon \to \infty$ we have $U\subset \mathbb{R}\in \tau$.

In oder to show (b) I'd take to arbitrary intervalls and add them together - but how do I do it formally?

Sadly, I don't really know how to show (c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty set belongs to $\tau$ trivially.

The set $\mathbb R$ belongs to $\tau$ because is $x\in U$ and you take $\varepsilon=1$, then $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset\mathbb R$.

If $A,B\in\tau$, take $x\in A\cap B$. There are $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon_1,x+\varepsilon_1)\subset A$ and $(x-\varepsilon_2,x+\varepsilon_2)\subset B$. So,\begin{align}\bigl(x-\min\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\},x+\min\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}\bigr)&=(x-\varepsilon_1,x+\varepsilon_1)\cap(x-\varepsilon_2,x+\varepsilon_2)\\&\subset A\cap B.\end{align}

And if $\alpha\subset\tau$ and $x\in\bigcup_{A\in\alpha}A$, then $x\in A_0$ for some $A_0\in\alpha$. So, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset A_0$. So,$$(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset\bigcup_{A\in\alpha}A.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of a) is not right. Note that interval size tending to zero is different from it being zero.
a) is vacuuously true for null set to put it differently there is no x the 'for all x'statement is always true. For $\mathbb{R}$  it clear that as for any real number say interval with size 1 is real.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you really understood the definition of $\tau$. A set $U$ is in $\tau$ if for each $x\in U$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ (which might depend on $x$) for which $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq U$. This has nothing to do with taking $\epsilon$ to $0$ or to $\infty$.

An example: for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $(x-1,x+1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. So for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we can take $\epsilon=1$. Hence $\mathbb{R}\in\tau$.

Now the empty set: well, if we suppose it isn't in $\tau$ then there must be some $x\in\emptyset$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is not contained in $\emptyset$. But this is a contradiction because there can't be any elements $x\in\emptyset$.

Now let's show $\tau$ is closed to unions. Let's say $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of sets in $\tau$ and we want to show their union is in $\tau$. Let $x\in\cup_{i\in I} A_i$. Then there is some $j\in I$ such that $x\in A_j$. Since $A_j\in\tau$ we know there is some $\epsilon>0$ for which $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq A_j\subseteq\cup_{i\in I} A_i$. So we proved exactly what we wanted, the union is in $\tau$ as well.

Finally, we have to show that $\tau$ is closed to finite intersections. Let $A,B\in\tau$. We want to show that their intersection is in $\tau$. Let $x\in A\cap B$. Since $x\in A$ and $A\in\tau$ there is $\epsilon_1>0$ for which $(x-\epsilon_1,x+\epsilon_1)\subseteq A$. Similarly, there is $\epsilon_2>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon_2,x+\epsilon_2)\subseteq B$. Let $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$. Then $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq A\cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your definition of a topology $\tau$ on $X,$ there is a typo in condition (c).

It is supposed to be $``$for $\alpha\in J,$ where $J$ is an index set $\Big($this index set $J$ is any of the following three types: (i) $J$ is either finite set, e.g. $\{1,2,\ldots,n\},$ where $n$ is a finite positive integer, (ii) $J$ is a countably infinite set, e.g. $\mathbb{N},$ the set of all positive integers, (iii) $J$ is an uncountable set, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}^c,$ the set of all irrational numbers$\Big),$ if $A_\alpha\in \tau,$ then   $\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}A_\alpha\in \tau."$

The meaning of condition (a) is $``$the empty set and the whole $X$ are the members of $\tau."$

The meaning of condition (b) is $``$the finite-intersection of members of $\tau$ is a member of $\tau."$

The meaning of condition (c) is $``$the arbitrary union of members of $\tau$ is a member of $\tau."$ $\big($Here the word arbitrary union refers to- the union of finite number of members, or the union of countably infinite number of members, or the union of uncountable number of members.$\big)$

If all these three conditions satisfies, then $\tau$ $\big($viz. a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)\big)$ is called a topology on $X,$ and $X$ is called a topological space endowed with a topology $\tau.$

Now, let us come to your example:

Given $X=\mathbb{R},$ the set of all real numbers, viz. $(-\infty, \, \infty).$

Given $\tau:=\Big\{U\,\,\Big| \, U\subseteq\mathbb{R},\,\,$if$\,\,x\in U,\,\,$then $\exists$ a finite$\,\,\epsilon_x \in (0, \infty)\,\,$s.t.$\,\,(x-\epsilon_x, \, x+\epsilon_x)\subseteq U\Big\}.$

Now let us see why $\tau$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}.$

For this, we need to check the conditions (a), (b), and (c). Remember, even if at least one of these conditions fails, then this $\tau$ will not be called as a topology on $\mathbb{R}.$

$\underline{\text{Condition (a).}}$  Note that $\varnothing\subset \mathbb{R}.$ But there is no $x\in \varnothing.$ Hence it is not required to check the condition: $``$Does there exists any finite $\,\epsilon_x\in (0, \infty)\,\,$s.t.$\,(x-\epsilon_x, \, x+\epsilon_x)\subseteq \varnothing,"\,$ as this condition is trivially true. $\big($To understand more about this logic, please read any textbook on conditional propositions: Let $p$ and $q$ be two propositions. Then the compound proposition $p\Longrightarrow q$ is a true proposition under three cases: (i) both $p$ and $q$ are true, (ii) both $p$ and $q$ are false, (iii) $p$ is false and $q$ is true. The truthness of above conditional statement follows from (iii).$\big)$ Therefore $\varnothing\in \tau.$

Now $\mathbb{R}\subseteq \mathbb{R}.$ Then for every real number $x\in \mathbb{R},$ one can choose, for instance, $\epsilon_x=1.$ Then note that $(x-1, \, x+1)\subset \mathbb{R}.$ Therefore $\mathbb{R}\in \tau.$

$\underline{\text{Condition (b).}}$ Let $U_1\in \tau$ and $U_2\in \tau.$ Then $U_1\cap U_2\subseteq \mathbb{R},$ as $U_1\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $U_2\subseteq \mathbb{R}.$

If $U_1\cap U_2=\varnothing,$ then $U_1\cap U_2\in \tau,\,$ by condition (a).

If $U_1\cap U_2\neq\varnothing,$ then $\exists$ some $x\in U_1\cap U_2.\,\,$ Since $x\in U_1,$ therefore $\exists$ some finite number, say $\epsilon_{1x}\in (0, \infty)$ s.t. $(x-\epsilon_{1x}, \, x+\epsilon_{1x})\subseteq U_1.\,\,$ Similarly, as $x\in U_2,$ therefore $\exists$ some finite number, say $\epsilon_{2x}\in (0, \infty)$ s.t. $(x-\epsilon_{2x}, \, x+\epsilon_{2x})\subseteq U_2.$ Let us define $\epsilon_x:=$ min$\{\epsilon_{1x},\, \epsilon_{2x}\}.$ Then $\epsilon_x\in (0, \infty)$ is also a finite number s.t. $(x-\epsilon_x, \, x+\epsilon_x)\subseteq U_1\cap U_2.\,\,$ As $\,x\,$ was arbitrary element in $U_1\cap U_2,$ so for every $x\in U_1\cap U_2,$ we can find some finite number $\epsilon_x\in (0, \infty),$ s.t. $(x-\epsilon_x, \, x+\epsilon_x)\subseteq U_1\cap U_2.$ Hence $U_1\cap U_2\in \tau.$

Now we prove that $\,U_1\cap\cdots \cap U_n\in \tau,\,\,$ whenever $\,U_1,\cdots, U_n\in \tau,$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is finite.

For this let us assume  $\,\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i\in \tau,\,$ $($where$\,\,n\geq 2).$

Then $\,\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}U_i=\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i\Big)\bigcap U_n.\,$ Denoting $\,\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}U_i=V,\,\,$then by using the previous argument, we have $V\cap U_n\in \tau,\,\,$ as $V\in \tau,\, U_n\in \tau.\,\,$Therefore $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}U_i\in \tau.\,\,$Hence by induction, any finite-intersection of members of $\tau$ is a member of $\tau.$

*Note: If we take the intersection of infinite collection of elements of $\tau,$ then it need not be a member of $\tau.$ For instance, let $U_n:=\big(-\frac{1}{n},\, \frac{1}{n}\big)\in \tau,$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Now if we take their intersection:

$$\bigcap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\Big(-\frac{1}{n},\,\frac{1}{n}\Big)=\{0\}\notin \tau,$$ as for the element $x=0\in \bigcap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\Big(-\frac{1}{n},\,\frac{1}{n}\Big),$ $\nexists\,$ any finite $\epsilon_0\in (0, \infty)\,$ s.t. $\,(0-\epsilon_0,\, 0+\epsilon_0)=(-\epsilon_0, \epsilon_0)\subseteq \bigcap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\Big(-\frac{1}{n},\,\frac{1}{n}\Big).$

$\underline{\text{Condition (c).}}\,$ Let $U_\alpha\in \tau,\,$ for each $\alpha\in J.\,$ We need to check whether $\,\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha\in \tau?$

Let $\,x\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha.\,$ $\big($If there is no $\,x\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha,\,$ then $\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha=\varnothing\in \tau,\,$ by condition (a).$\big)\,$ Then $\,x\in U_\alpha,\,$ for some $\alpha\in J.\,$ Since $U_\alpha\in \tau,\,$ therefore $\exists$ some finite $\,\epsilon_{\alpha x}\in (0, \infty)\,$ s.t.$\,(x-\epsilon_{\alpha x},\,\, x+\epsilon_{\alpha x})\subseteq U_\alpha.\,$ But again as $U_\alpha\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha,\,\,$ so by transitivity of $\,\subseteq,\,$ we have 
$$(x-\epsilon_{\alpha x},\,\, x+\epsilon_{\alpha x})\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha.$$  This condition is true for every $x\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha,\,$ as our chosen $x$ was arbitrary element of $\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha.\,$  Hence $\,\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha\in \tau.$

All the above verifications forces to claim that $\mathbb{R}$ is a topological space endowed with a topology $\tau.$